# Is the 17 June 2016 operation legaly illigitimate?

Tags: security, the-dao

It has been stated that since the creator of the DAO have called the contracts code as the only legal statement, all things that the code allows are legitimate.
As a counterargument it was said that code can't be a legal contract in most juristictions.
What is true?
http://pastebin.com/CcGUBgDG

Comment: Legal according to what jurisdiction?

Comment: It's unclear what a good answer to this question should contain, and FYI check [this meta thread](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/325/87) regarding ongoing DAO questions.

Comment: Don't know what it says about a broader understanding of law and the acceptance of law as an academic discipline, that you flag this question as 'primarily opinion based'. 
What the answer should contain? a sound derivation of a conclusion based on the axioms of a 2000 years old discipline called the Jurisprudence a.k.a.: the science, study, and theory of law.